# Symfony: Web debug toolbar icons disappeared

Tags: debugging, deployment, symfony1

Just moved a symfony project from local (win) to server (linux), and the icons in the web debug toolbar have disappeared. Only the image alts remain so I guess it's a path issue with the images. Basically, I see "Time 300ms" instead of "[icon] 300ms" for each of the items.

I'm a little worried that some other paths aren't broken as well that are going to be a pain to find.

Has anyone had/resolved this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution is to define an alias in your httpd.conf (or whatever the name of your apache conf)

Answer (score 3):

Solved...

It's a missing alias, but copying this folder in its entirety:

```
/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf/
```

to...

```
/web/
```

... fixes the paths for the toolbar as a quick solution.